# Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver'

Tags: php, yii2, xampp, yii2-advanced-app, linux-mint

I have just installed yii2.0 advanced on linux mint 18.2, using XAMPP for Linux 7.0.23, and my php yii migrate/up command doesn't work. It shows:

```
with message 'could not find driver'

in /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:584
```

I had googled it and i got several results. There, I read 'use php -m command'; you will realize which php have been used by your system. But I do not know what will be the expected output after running the command.

```
 with message 'could not find driver'

in /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:584

Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(928): yii\db\Connection->open()
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(915): yii\db\Connection->getMasterPdo()
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(219): yii\db\Connection->getSlavePdo()
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(910): yii\db\Command->prepare(true)
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(362): yii\db\Command->queryInternal('fetchAll', NULL)
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php(199): yii\db\Command->queryAll()
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/Schema.php(98): yii\db\mysql\Schema->findColumns(Object(yii\db\TableSchema))
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php(152): yii\db\mysql\Schema->loadTableSchema('migration')
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/MigrateController.php(194): yii\db\Schema->getTableSchema('{{%migration}}', true)
#9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(814): yii\console\controllers\MigrateController->getMigrationHistory(NULL)
#10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/BaseMigrateController.php(155): yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->getNewMigrations()
#11 [internal function]: yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->actionUp(0)
#12 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(156): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#14 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(128): yii\base\Controller->runAction('up', Array)
#15 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(523): yii\console\Controller->runAction('up', Array)
#16 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(180): yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate/up', Array)
#17 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(147): yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate/up', Array)
#18 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(380): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#19 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yii/yii(27): yii\base\Application->run()
#20 {main}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need install `pdo_mysql` module.

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

After that check your `phpinfo();`

Comment: sir, I am new in Yii2.0 advanced. I am sorry for asking this silly question how to check phpinfo() means from where to check and what ?

Comment: You are Welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error too. *pdo_mysql* driver was installed and shown in phpinfo(), web application run fine, but from command line it could not find driver. Solution was to provide php version

```
cd /var/www/html/project_folder
php7.1 application/yii.php controller/method
```